# How to change background color of events array in FSCalendar swift 3?

Tags: swift3, fscalendar

I'm having an 2arrays of dates and want to set different colors for particular event please help how to do this.

**I'm trying to implement following code but its not working its returning nil no color effects no error nothing m stucked on this please help.**

```
import UIKit
import FSCalendar

class myCalendarViewController: UIViewController,FSCalendarDelegate,FSCalendarDataSource,FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

    var presentdays = [String]()
    var absentdays = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

fileprivate let gregorian: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter1: DateFormatter = {
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
   return formatter
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance,  titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
         presentdays = ["2017-06-03",
                        "2017-06-06",
                        "2017-06-12",
                        "2017-06-25"]

         absentdays = ["2017-06-10",
                       "2017-06-18",
                       "2017-06-15",
                       "2017-06-16"]

let datestring2 : String = dateFormatter1.string(from:date)

if presentdays.contains(datestring2)
{
    return UIColor.green
}
else if absentdays.contains(datestring2)
{
    return UIColor.red
}
else{
    return nil
}

}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dateFormat` of `DateFormatter` and string date in array doesn't match so changes the dateFormat to `yyyy-MM-dd` and then check array contains object or not.

```
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter1: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()
```

Comment: @BugFinder Welcome mate :)

Comment: hey @Nirav can you guide me on how to make api call of my above question's web service ? below is my API link   http://ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/AttendanceDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=2&month=6&year=2017                                           will you please guide me ?

Comment: check this out                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588656/how-to-make-api-call-for-this-web-service-to-fetch-array-of-present-and-absent-d. :)

Comment: but I can't figure out dude how to make it array of date objects from this JSON Response :(

Comment: @BugFinder You need to show the code of how you are making API call i'm not talking about making array of dates.

Comment: hey mate will you help me to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670289/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-specific-body-and-also-want-to-access-token