# How to make API call for this web service to fetch array of present and absent dates separately in swift?

Tags: json, swift3, fscalendar

it was my previous question to simply display static data on FSCalendar using 2 arrays of present and absent days.

[How to change background color of events array in FSCalendar swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581620/how-to-change-background-color-of-events-array-in-fscalendar-swift-3)

now I want to fetch the present and absent dates from the following json response in the format of 2array named : present and absent want to display on FSCalendar according to my previous question.

How to parse the same?. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "Present": [
  {
  "Student_ID": 2,
  "LeaveLetterApplied": null,
  "Message": null,
  "Date": "2017-06-04T00:00:00",
  "Notify": null,
  "Status": "Present"
 },
 {
  "Student_ID": 2,
  "LeaveLetterApplied": null,
  "Message": null,
  "Date": "2017-06-05T00:00:00",
  "Notify": null,
  "Status": "Present"
}],
  "Absent": [
   {
     "Student_ID": 2,
     "LeaveLetterApplied": "",
     "Message": "",
     "Date": "2017-06-01T00:00:00",
     "Notify": null,
     "Status": "Absent"
   },
   {
     "Student_ID": 2,
     "LeaveLetterApplied": "",
     "Message": "",
     "Date": "2017-06-02T00:00:00",
     "Notify": null,
     "Status": "Absent"
   },
  {
     "Student_ID": 2,
     "LeaveLetterApplied": "",
     "Message": "",
     "Date": "2017-06-03T00:00:00",
     "Notify": null,
     "Status": "Absent"
  },
  {
    "Student_ID": 2,
    "LeaveLetterApplied": "Applied",
    "Message": "Sick Leave",
    "Date": "2017-06-06T00:00:00",
    "Notify": null,
    "Status": "Absent"
 }
],
   "No_Of_Working_Days": 6,
   "No_Of_Present_Days": 2,
   "Percentage": 0
 }
```

**Below is the code m using to parse :**

```
func getdateFromJSON()
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/AttendanceDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=1&month=1&year=2017")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error)
        in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            print("Error:",error)
            return
        }
        let httpstatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if httpstatus?.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
                let responseString = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                let presentdetails = responseString["Present"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
                let absentdetails = responseString["Absent"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
                print(absentdetails)
                print(presentdetails)
               // dont know what to do next :(

                }

            else
            {
                print("No data got from URL")
            }
        }
        else{
            print("error httpstatus code is :",httpstatus?.statusCode)
        }

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

screenshot [image: Appearance]

**Error Log :**

**2017-06-17 10:23:50.671 ezSchool[1848:24475] -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (placeholderType) user defined inspected property on (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475] -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (firstWeekday) user defined inspected property on (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475] -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.673 ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (headerHeight) user defined inspected property on (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.673 ezSchool[1848:24475] -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
2017-06-17 10:23:50.673 ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (headerTitleTextSize) user defined inspected property on (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0
Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000005cbc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/AttendanceDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=2&month=6&year=2017, NSErrorFailingURLKey=ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/AttendanceDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=2&month=6&year=2017, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL})**

Comment: What you want, are you expecting two array of string with date in format `2017-06-02` ?

Comment: yes all the dates of present and absent in two different array like I have displayed in my previous question.

Comment: hey Nirav what should I do in this following method of FSCalendar.  filldefaultcolorsfor as I implement in my previous question ?

Comment: May be you need to reload your `FSCalendar`, `calendar.reloadData()`

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: This must be related to `FSCalendar` you need to check this on github issue of `FSCalendar`.

Comment: hey mate what should I do with this issue yaar :(

Comment: Search here about that error https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues may be that will helps you if it still not helps ask a new question here

Comment: I don't think so they will help me coz there are so many issues are still pending.

Comment: are yaar these guys have banned me from asking the new question hadd hai yaar :(

Comment: I mean seriously its so embarrassing they will allow me to ask after 6months hey Nirav will you please post this crash on my behalf? or have to create the new account what should I do you say.

Comment: @NiravD mate its me in new avatar :D and my question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601380/trying-to-reload-fscalendar-with-json-data-but-it-crashes

Comment: @NiravD hey what to do if i want to parse only 2digits of date from the date object. ?

Comment: yes and one more thing this FSCalendar will only accept the date format right so i think we have to convert in date so will you please update your answer? see the error log what it says unrecongnized selector.

Comment: That error is not related about date ? You are just using one method to change color how it is related to that and what you want to convert to date that method already return date

Comment: ok and what about to parse only dd ?

Comment: Then only use `dd` dateFormat with `DateFormatter`.

Comment: you mean here ? dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Not there make one more date formatter and set its dateFormat to only `dd`  and use that dateFormatter in second `flatMap` instead of `dateFormatter1`.

Comment: ok mate will try it.

Comment: @NiravD hi mate morning will you please guide me how to solve this question I stucked on it since so many days I can't figure out how to achieve this. coding as well as design perspective too :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985996/how-to-create-a-multiple-autocompletion-textfields-which-works-as-a-filter-in-sw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, you just need to use `DateFormatter` to get your formatted date. Also correct `JSON` dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`.

First of all declare two instance property in your class of type `[String]` named `presentDateArray` and `absentDateArray`.

```
var presentDateArray = [String]()
var absentDateArray = [String]()
```

Now initialize these two array in your response completion block this way.

```
if let responseJSON = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any],
    let presentdetails = responseJSON["Present"] as? [[String:Any]],
    let Absentdetails = responseJSON["Absent"] as? [[String:Any]] {

     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
     self.presentDateArray = presentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(for: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap { dateFormatter1.string(from:$0) }
     self.absentDateArray = Absentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(for: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap { dateFormatter1.string(from:$0) }
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         calendar.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Now simply use this two array in your delegate of method of

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance,  titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

    let datestring2 : String = dateFormatter1.string(from:date)

    if presentDateArray.contains(datestring2) {
        return UIColor.green
    }
    else if presentDateArray.contains(datestring2) {
       return UIColor.red
    }
    else {
       return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks buddy will update my code as per your answer and let you know. :)

Comment: @BugFinder Ok Will wait for your response

Comment: and what about color effect ? check the appearance method in my previous question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581620/how-to-change-background-color-of-events-array-in-fscalendar-swift-3/44581711?noredirect=1#comment76165119_44581711

Comment: @BugFinder Is this method not getting called `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance,  titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {` when you reload the calendar

Comment: yes I know mate then how to reload according to appearance?

Comment: What does that mean ? Is it getting called or not ?

Comment: check my question want to display this fetched array of date using color effect I have attached the screenshot .

Comment: waiting for your reply :(

Comment: Currently out from my Mac will respond you later

Comment: morning morning mate :) have tried your answer its giving me the error log. I'm posting this log as an another comment.

Comment: @BugFinder Don't know about this log it is not related to above code looks like it is related to FSCalendar