# Trying to Reload FSCalendar with JSon data but it crashes

Tags: swift3, fscalendar

this question is linked with the my previous account's question.

[How to make API call for this web service to fetch array of present and absent dates separately in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588656/how-to-make-api-call-for-this-web-service-to-fetch-array-of-present-and-absent-d)

**code**

```
import UIKit
import FSCalendar

class AttendenceViewController : UIViewController, FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance
{

@IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

var presentdays : Array = [String]()
var absentdays : Array = [String]()
fileprivate let gregorian: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter1: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
    formatter2.dateFormat = "dd"
    return formatter2
}()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getdateFromJSON()


}



func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
    let datestring2 : String = dateFormatter1.string(from: date)
    if presentdays.contains(datestring2)
    {
        return UIColor.green
    }
    else if absentdays.contains(datestring2)
    {
        return UIColor.red
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }

}
func getdateFromJSON()
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/AttendanceDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=2&month=6&year=2017")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error)
        in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            print("Error:",error)
            return
        }
        let httpstatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if httpstatus?.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
                if let responseJSON = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any],
                    let presentdetails = responseJSON["Present"] as? [[String:Any]],
                    let Absentdetails = responseJSON["Absent"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"


                    self.presentdays = presentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap {
                        self.dateFormatter2.string(from:$0)
                    }
                    self.absentdays = Absentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap { self.dateFormatter2.string(from:$0) }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                    self.calendar.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                }

            else
            {
                print("No data got from URL")
            }
        }
        else{
            print("error httpstatus code is :",httpstatus?.statusCode)
        }

    }
    task.resume()

}

 }
```

I'm attaching the error log here please help thanks in advance.

**ERROR LOG**

> 2017-06-17 10:23:50.671 ezSchool[1848:24475]
>   -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.672
>   ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (**placeholderType**) user defined
>   inspected property on (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor
>   unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475]
>   -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.672
>   ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (**firstWeekday**) user defined
>   inspected property on (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor
>   unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475]
>   -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.673 ezSchool[1848:24475]
>   Failed to set (**headerHeight**) user defined inspected property on
>   (FSCalendar): -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.673
>   ezSchool[1848:24475] -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17
>   10:23:50.673 ezSchool[1848:24475] Failed to set (**headerTitleTextSize**)
>   user defined inspected property on (FSCalendar):
>   -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: @Aravind A R please check my updated questions with code.

Comment: Did you set FSCalendar's delegate and datasource correctly ?

Comment: @AravindAR yes sir

Comment: can you provide any value that you are getting inside datestring2. After executing this expression-  let datestring2 : String = dateFormatter1.string(from: date)

Comment: sorry sir but I didnt get your question.

Comment: Please provide the value of  datestring2 insitde  func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor?

Comment: let datestring2 : String = dateFormatter1.string(from: date) value is already there date itself is a value

Comment: Print its value and put it here as comment

Comment: 2017-05-28
2017-05-29
2017-05-30
2017-05-31
2017-06-01
2017-06-02
2017-06-03
2017-06-04
2017-06-05
2017-06-06

Comment: I have added a possible solution to your question please check, whether it is working fine?

Comment: while debugging the error of unrecognised selector is comes at the viewdidload().

Comment: @AravindAR sure sir thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the function `getdateFromJSON()` with

```
func getdateFromJSON()
        {
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/AttendanceDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=2&month=6&year=2017")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error)
                in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else
                {
                    print("Error:",error ?? "error")
                    return
                }
                let httpstatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                if httpstatus?.statusCode == 200
                {
                    if data?.count != 0
                    {
                        if let responseJSON = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any],
                            let presentdetails = responseJSON["Present"] as? [[String:Any]],
                            let Absentdetails = responseJSON["Absent"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"


                            self.presentdays = presentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap {
                                self.dateFormatter1.string(from:$0)
                            }
                            self.absentdays = Absentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap { self.dateFormatter1.string(from:$0) }
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {
                                    self.calendar.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("No data got from URL")
                    }
                }
                else{
                    print("error httpstatus code is :",httpstatus?.statusCode ?? "5")
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Please see whether the below attached image is your desired output 
[image]

Comment: sir as I said this error comes at the viewdidload() otherwise whole code is working fine.

Comment: I'm sorry man but I didn't find anything that would crash at viewDidLoad. :(

Comment: no crash but the error log of unrecognised selector. :(

Comment: I'm sorry but please tell me the exact error 
is it showing 2017-06-17 10:23:50.671 ezSchool[1848:24475] -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0 2017-06-17 10:23:50.672 ezSchool[1848:24475]

As you have highlighted on the question or any other?

Comment: error log type is same but the fields are different check my edited error log  have marked all the field value as a bold.

Comment: I'm sorry mate but when I used your code in a sample project that I've created, it compiles and doesn't show the compilation error like [UICachedDeviceWhiteColor unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000059ec0  in viewDidLoad :(

Comment: the only problem m facing is to set color for present and absent in fillDefaultColor. :( hey is there any other way to represent the attendance like this ?

Comment: I believe you were not able to compile the project right?

Comment: no it compiled and ran successfully but no appearance change of output.

Comment: hey you said that you have created a sample project right ? have you got the output ?

Comment: The api is not getting called it shows an error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL 
Are you getting the same error or are you getting data from api

Comment: I'm getting the output

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot in the answer please verify, I believe it is your desired output

Comment: I have only made changes to your code as I have mentioned in the answer.
I have replaced self.presentdays = presentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap {
                        self.dateFormatter2.string(from:$0)
                    }
with 
self.presentdays = presentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap {
                        self.dateFormatter1.string(from:$0)
                    }

Comment: And replaced 
 self.absentdays = Absentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap { self.dateFormatter2.string(from:$0) }
With
 self.absentdays = Absentdetails.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0["Date"] as! String) }.flatMap { self.dateFormatter1.string(from:$0) }

Comment: I'm sorry man I am not having access to gmail right now. I have copied the getdateFromJSON function for your convenience.

Comment: sir please update your answer with filldefaultcolor method.

Comment: hello sir can you help me to solve my new question?. A lot of thanks in advance :) . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670289/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-specific-body-and-how-to-access-token-from-t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147326/discussion-between-aravind-a-r-and-silvervein).