# Index out of range error while displaying date into tableview cell using swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Hello all I have a custom `UITableViewCell` inside my tableview with 2 labels and one imageview. In first label I am fetching the array of notification message which will running fine in **second label m fetching the array of dates in this case m getting the error message Index out of Range**.can anyone help me how to solve it.thanks in advance

**attached is JSON response here :**

```
{
    "Notification_Details":
    [
        {
            "student_id": 2,
            "date": "2017-06-03T00:00:00",
            "message": "Notification Message 3"
        },
        {
            "student_id": 2,
            "date": "2017-06-02T00:00:00",
            "message": "Notification Message 2"
        },
        {
            "student_id": 2,
            "date": "2017-06-01T00:00:00",
            "message": "Notification Message 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

and below is the code m using to fetch the json and load into tableview cell.

```
import UIKit

class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var mytable: UITableView!

var notilabell : Array = [String]()
var datelabel : Array = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.getnotiJSON()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return notilabell.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NotiCellTableViewCell

           cell.noti.text = notilabell[indexPath.row]
    cell.datenotification.text = datelabel[indexPath.row]



    return cell

}

func getnotiJSON()
{
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Student/NotificationDetails?schoolid=1&studentid=2")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error)
        in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            print("Error:",error)
            return
        }
        let httpstatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if httpstatus?.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
            let responseString = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                     let notiarray = responseString?.value(forKey: "Notification_Details") as? NSArray

                        for notifi in notiarray!
                        {
                            let notidict = notifi as? NSDictionary

                                let notiname = notidict?.value(forKey: "message")

                                    self.notilabell.append(notiname as! String)

                            let notidat = notidict?.value(forKey: "message") as! String
                            let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
                            dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
                           let mystring = dateformatter.string(from: Date())
                            let yourdate = dateformatter.date(from: mystring)
                            dateformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                            let mynewdate = dateformatter.string(from: yourdate!)
                                    self.notilabell.append(mynewdate as! String)

                        }

                DispatchQueue.main.async                                 {
                    self.mytable.reloadData()
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                print("No data got from URL")
            }
        }
        else{
            print("error httpstatus code is :",httpstatus?.statusCode)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is with the date formatter that you are using while parsing the date. Also the key from which you are dates are also wrong. Try using

```
    let notidat = notidict?.value(forKey: "date") as! String
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"
```

You are appending dates to `notilabell` array and not `datelabel` array
change below code

```
let mynewdate = dateformatter.string(from: yourdate!)
self.notilabell.append(mynewdate as! String)
```

**To**

```
let mynewdate = dateformatter.string(from: yourdate!)
self.datelabel.append(mynewdate as! String)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. I tried your code but still getting the same error at cell.datenotification.text = datelabel[indexPath.row] Index out of Range

Comment: @silvervein I have updated the answer it would be great if you could try it and update the status.

Comment: hey will you plz help me to solve my previous question on stackoverflow?

Comment: Please post the link as comment. I will try.

Comment: sir this question is linked with 2 more questions of my previous account too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601380/trying-to-reload-fscalendar-with-json-data-but-it-crashes It would be of great help thank you

Comment: But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588656/how-to-make-api-call-for-this-web-service-to-fetch-array-of-present-and-absent-d this one is marked as answered right